# Reconnecting to Kafka with node-rdkafka is slow & inconsistent

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I have kafka and zookeeper running in some local docker containers.

I have a node.js codebase which uses node-rdkafka to connect to kafka as a consumer. We'll call this codebase **"the consumer"**

The consumer uses the code shown here to connect to kafka:
https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/consumer-flow.md

When attempting to connect to an existing Kafka instance, I get this output:

```
consumer ready.{"name":"rdkafka#consumer-1"}
```

But then my code which receives and processes messages never fires, or takes several mins (apparently 5 to 10 mins sometimes) before it begins firing.

To ensure that messages *are* being produced, I use the script `kafka-console-consumer.sh` which came with kafka to observe the message stream. Sure enough, PLENTY of data is coming.

It appears that connecting sometimes fails, and sometimes takes a very long time to connect.

Here's the kafka log during this time:

```
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:55:37,963] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1001]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:55:48,576] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 1 (kafka.network.Processor)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:55:53,185] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to restabilize group video-caption-consumer with old generation 24 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:56:18,577] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Stabilized group video-caption-consumer generation 25 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:56:18,626] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Assignment received from leader for group video-caption-consumer for generation 25 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:58:24,951] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to restabilize group video-caption-consumer with old generation 25 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:58:51,643] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Stabilized group video-caption-consumer generation 26 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 20:58:51,648] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Assignment received from leader for group video-caption-consumer for generation 26 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 21:01:14,231] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to restabilize group video-caption-consumer with old generation 26 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 21:01:16,414] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Stabilized group video-caption-consumer generation 27 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
kafka_1      | [2017-04-27 21:01:16,419] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Assignment received from leader for group video-caption-consumer for generation 27 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
```

It just repeats that pattern infinitely.

Ideas?

For what it's worth, I used the kakfa-node module for a while too; that had similar issues, though I can't be sure if the same exact problem.

Comment: What sort of config options are you using? This looks like the consumer group is struggling to rebalance which can indicate you are polling for to many messages at once or maybe not polling often enough because of some message processing. Sharing your config and the code if you can may help.

Comment: my exact code can be seen here (https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/consumer-flow.md), and the only configs I set were as you see in the new Kafka.KafkaConsumer() constructor.

As for the configs in zookeeper and kafka, I'm using the entirely out of the box quickstart setup https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: Hmm so it's a pretty out of the box example. What do you get on the consumer side for logging? If you include the debug enabling code do you see anything repeated while waiting for the connection to be established? It could be the docker containers don't have enough memory and things are thrashing in connection establishment. Maybe bump the container for the broker up to 1G and make sure Xmx is at least 512M and give the client 512M?

Comment: What are your Kafka server's values for `group.max.session.timeout.ms` and `group.min.session.timeout.ms`? I've had issues getting consumers to connect (with a log output similar to yours) when my consumer's `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms` didn't fall between the server's range

Comment: Update: This problem disappeared shortly after posting this, and I don't know what solved it. I feel a bit guilty not responding to the comments here, but since I can no longer reproduce my own issue... I can't provide reliable diagnostic feedback :(

Answer (score 0):

As long as nobody has a good answer, I'll share my solution...

Eventually I stopped running kafka in a docker container, which appears to have been the cause. I instead ran it old school, following [The Quick Start Guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

This solved my problems, and so the problem may not have been the fault of `node-rdkafka` at all. In fact, we've been running `node-rdkafka` successfully in production for nearly a year now, without any issue.

In the end I don't have hard, satisfactory answers, only suspicion and a lot of painful memories trying to get kafka to work in a container.  It was sweet relief when I finally gave up on dockerized kafka. Only some of my colleagues seem to have shared my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue running Kafka as a docker container. It is all about the docker network bridge type. My topology was running Kafka, producer, and consumers on the same Docker bridge network. I thought it was the best manner to have a Kafka environment for development matters.

However, both consumer and producer were unable to connect to the Kafka server properly. After a lot of tentatives, I realized that both producer and consumer must run on the host network.

So, to that end just put `--net host` parameter when you run consumer or producer on Docker. And then you are able to connect to Kafka by `localhost` pointing to the correct port.

```
$ docker run -d --net host --name kafka-consumer kafka-consumer 
$ docker run -d --net host --name kafka-producer kafka-producer
```